# class property not working excel vba

Tags: class, excel, vba

I'm trying to teach myself how to use vba class module.  Here's my class module (named `clsWorkingRange`).  Here's the module:

```
Option Explicit

Private pSheetName As String
Private pColNum As Integer

Public Property Get SheetName() As String
    SheetName = pSheetName
End Property

Public Property Let SheetName(SheetName As String)
    pSheetName = SheetName
End Property

Public Property Get ColNum() As Integer
    ColNum = pColNum
End Property

Public Property Let ColNum(ColNumb As Integer)
    pColNum = ColNum
End Property

Public Function Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet_get As String, column_num As Integer)
'worksheet is the name of a sheet in the form of a string
    Dim ws As Worksheet:             Set ws = Worksheets(work_sheet_get)
    Dim rows_count As Long:                 rows_count = ws.Cells(rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row
    Get_Rows_Generic = rows_count
End Function
```

I'm trying to sue the class here (in a separate module):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_the_class()
    Dim first_class_example As New clsWorkingRange

    first_class_example.SheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"
    first_class_example.ColNum = 1

        Debug.Print first_class_example.SheetName
        Debug.Print first_class_example.ColNum

    Dim row_count_test As Long
    row_count_test = first_class_example.Get_Rows_Generic(first_class_example.SheetName, first_class_example.ColNum)

    MsgBox "row count is " & row_count_test

End Sub
```

`Debug.Print first_class_example.ColNum` prints `0`.  Why isn't the property coming through as 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just becase you should change this

```
Public Property Let ColNum(ColNumb As Integer)
    pColNum = ColNum
End Property
```

to this:

```
Public Property Let ColNum(ColNumb As Integer)
    pColNum = ColNumb
End Property
```

;).